# Calculating effective bit precision of DAC due to range restriction

Tags: dac

Say I have a 16-bit DAC which outputs a range from 0-5V. My application only requires an output from 4-5V. I am interested in the effective precision of the DAC due to this range restriction.

Is the formula 16 - log((5 - 0)/(5 - 4))/log(2) = 13.68 bits valid?

Comment: Why not use the full range of the DAC between 4 and 5 V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your result is correct. A 16 bit DAC has 2^16 = 65536 steps, but over 5V range. You are only using 1/5 of the range, so are using 13107 steps. Since 2^14 = 16384 it is clearly a bit less than 14 bits. [Log base 2 (n) = log (n)/ log (2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm) so log base 2(13107) = 13.68 bits.

Comment: Yes, you'll get back one of these (approximately) 13,108 different values, giving log(13,108)/log(2)=13.68 bits. However, since what marketing people call a "16-bit DAC" has a somewhat lower effective number of bits -- the ENOB should be documented in the datasheet of the DAC -- your effective precision (ENOB) will also be somewhat lower than 13.68 bits. Hopefully that will still be more than adequate for your application; otherwise you'll have to improve the ENOB by one technique (18 bit DAC?) or another (voltage divider and op-amp? software dithering and low-pass filter?).